# dynamically edit template of iron-list

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, iron-list

At first, i know, there are many questions about iron-list. But mostly about editing items and not whole template inside iron-list..

My code is really extremely complicated and posting it is pointless. I am working on data-tables which are using `iron-list`. I have element called `diamond-listing` and inside this `diamond-listing` i have `iron-list`.

**You can image this like**: Parent element define `<template>` with some content inside it, and child element (diamond-listing) will render this template as a table

Of course `diamond-listing` is used multiple times in my application and always with different template. For example: page users have columns with userID, userName etc.. and on page stations there are columns stationID, address etc.. with different number of columns. Every pagea has it's own `<template>` which i am trying to propagate to `diamond-listing`. For example:

```
    <diamond-listing as="user" id="permissionsTable" type="pagination" pagination-items-per-page="6" header-data="{{headerData}}" address="/user/" loading="{{loading}}">
        <div id="test" slot="content">
            <template>
                <div class="diamond-row" on-tap="_openUrl" info$="/user/[[user.id]]">
                    <diamond-item text="{{user.username}}"></diamond-item>
                    <diamond-item text="{{user.partner.name}}"></diamond-item>
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </diamond-listing>
```

What i managed to do is to make it work in shadow dom using `<slot>` and simply rewrite `<template>` inside `<iron-list>`, but here we are.. For example using Firefox, which doesn't support webcomponents, there isn't `<template>` as a child of `<iron-list>` (because there is no shadow-dom) so there is no way how to update `<template>` and render iron-list.

**What i tried:**

1) Find template inside iron-list and use `removeChild` and `appendChild` functions.

```
var test = this.querySelector("#test template");
this.$$("#diamondList").removeChild(this.$$("#diamondList template"));
this.$$("#diamondList").appendChild(test);
```

Without success.

2) Define in HTML empty iron-list without any template inside it. And then in javascript add template dynamically. Without success. ( iron-list is crying it requires template)

3) Create dynamically iron-list using `document.createElement`

```
var test = this.querySelector("#test template");
var list = document.createElement("iron-list");
list.appendChild(test);
list.as = this.as;
list.items = [{"username":"test","partner":{"name":"Test partner","id":1}}];
list.id = "diamondList";
```

result: same as 2) ...

Is there a way, how to update `template` which is used to render all items in `iron-list`?

Or create iron-list with defined template inside JS ?

Or somehow do it with dom-repeat ? I won't have more than 10 items in listing, since it's fully pagination listing. ( this is propably simplest solution, but i don't know how to render `<template>` for every iteration

Answer (score 0):

Here is one general answer, don't know if it will work for your case:

In Polymer, recommended way of manipulating the DOM is by manipulating the data, not by removeChild or appendChild.

For example,

- if you have list of users as: var users_array = [....];

create the iron-list as:

```
<iron-list date="users_array">
  <template>
  ...
  <template>
</iron-list>
```

- adding and removing elements in users_array will affect the iron-list
  immediately.

Comment: definitely not. I have absolutely different schemas and everything in <template> need to change. There are different elements, different, bindings, on-tap events and so on. so definitely not this way. every single listing has its own templae which needs to be rendered

Answer (score 0):

Use a `dom-if` or use `hidden` inside the `iron-list`.

```
<iron-list items="[[items]]">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.isType1]]">
      <!-- item1 -->
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.isType2]]">
      <!-- item2 -->
    </template>
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. This would be great until your application has less than 5 pages +- .. My app is big and imagine a file with 20 ( in future even more) different templates inside it. what a mess isn't it? But you are right this might work. I'll wait with bounty few days if someone finds better solution

Comment: You could have an element for each type of layout. So inside each `dom-if` would just be a single line passing the current item to the correct layout element.

Comment: well that is better. but isn't it a little bit problem with number of imports? i am trying to avoid surplus imports. Because i think it is causing slower load screen. Am i right?

Comment: I couldn't say for certain. Have you tried the Lighthouse chrome extension to do some performance metrics?